# Speed up join for table with no indexes or unique values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

The query looks something like this:

```
SELECT Year, Month, ..., Count, ISNULL(PreviousCount, 0)
  FROM @Data AS DataTable
       LEFT JOIN @Data AS PreviousData
       ON PreviousData.Year = DataTable.Year - 1
         AND ...
```

- The data is extracted from an excel spreadsheet into a sqlserver
  database.
- There a no unique values.
- I can't use an `INNER JOIN` as there won't always be data for the previous year.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  And, edit your question and show sample data and desired results.

Comment: How much data is there in the `@Data` table? Have you tried using a temporary table in place of table variable. You can build index on the temp table and that should help.

Comment: I am using SQL SERVER 2014. The `@data' table contains about 700k rows and 18 columns. I will try the temp table to see if that speeds it up.

Comment: Thanks, the temp table solved the problem. The query went from 25min to 2 seconds.